# Can only use the '.sparse' accessor with Sparse data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I performed OHE on my data with sparse=True parameter - which doesn't seem doing anything?

I've try:

```
# One Hot Encoding
df_ohe = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=cats, drop_first=True, sparse=True)
df_ohe = df_ohe.sparse.to_coo().tocsr() #Explicitely convert
df_ohe.memory_usage().sum()
```

...which returns

> AttributeError: Can only use the '.sparse' accessor with Sparse data.

Help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to import the csr_matrix method (which converts numpy arrays to a sparse matrix) using

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
```

You can then just write

```
df_ohe = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=cats, drop_first=True)
df_ohe = csr_matrix(df_ohe.values)
```

So note that here I removed the `sparse=True` from the get_dummies method and then changed the syntax for converting to a sparse matrix.

Comment: I marked that as correct answer but I'm running out of memory with that sparse matrix over a dataframe having a lot of columns after OHE.

Comment: Thanks for that. After a bit of research it looks like there is a bug in get_dummies that is causing this issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51709377/pd-get-dummies-dataframe-same-size-when-sparse-true-as-when-sparse-false and https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/18686. To solve the memory issues might require some hacking.

Comment: Yeah, I found that too. It's quite recent version update, it was working previously. Hope it gets solved soon. Thanks for the comment!